# how do we define the udf to pass struct which has arrays?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to filter a column and the column scheme is a struct with three arrays in dataframe in spark.  I want to filter the empty row that the struct is empty.
here is schema

```
root
 |-- tdid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- receiveTime: long (nullable = true)
 |-- appList: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- install: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- open: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- run: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

here is data example

```
+--------------------+-------------+------------+
|                tdid|  receiveTime|     appList|
+--------------------+-------------+------------+
|3caaad47ecd54d952...|1562067645846|[[], [], []]|
|350fbebd32146c6d6...|1562067645661|[[], [], []]|
|3c4cba8c07ff07c24...|1562067646634|[[], [], []]|
|3547875587e75a89e...|1562067645758|[[], [], []]|
|38d4eff2bb456b79d...|1562067645994|[[], [], []]|
|345c4fb84ca2420ff...|1562067641035|[[], [], []]|
|3986feee5a4d24ea3...|1562067647467|[[], [], []]|
|371d808ac62ff4820...|1562067648884|[[], [], []]|
|341dfd0f6b00dfde4...|1562067654488|[[], [], []]|
```

```scala
val filterAppList = (appList: Row) => {

    /*var installList = appList.getAs[Seq[Long]]("install")*/
    if(appList.isNullAt(0) && appList.isNullAt(1) && appList.isNullAt(2)) {
        null
    } else {
        appList
    }
}
val filter_AppList = functions.udf(filterAppList)
val part_withNull = part.select(functions.col("tdid"), functions.col("receiveTime"), filter_AppList(functions.col("appList")))
part_withNull.show(10)
```

I always get the wrong message

```
Name: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Message: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported
StackTrace:   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:780)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:715)
  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:824)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:714)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:711)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3340)
```

Comment: What output do you want in the end?, you may not need udf at all for this.

Comment: issue here with return type, UDF cannot return Row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df.withColumn("is_null", when(col("appList.install").isNull 
&& col("appList.open").isNull && col("appList.run").isNull, null).otherwise(col("appList"))
```

Comment: yes. final, I take way like this to resolve my problem.